# Apply *ngif tag to current scope/table row

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table built in HTML and AngularJS (Angular 2). I am using an ngIf directive to trigger an editable fields from the scope where it was clicked. 
If a user clicks "Edit" button, then all the fields in ONLY that row should become editable.

See my code below. Currently, when user clicks "Edit" button, then it will make all the input fields in the table editable. How can I prevent this? Only the row inside the scope of the "Edit" button should become editable. I am not sure how to accomplish this using AngularJS.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let location of locations">
      <td *ngIf="!editing">{{location.apName}}</td>
      <td id="apNameInpit" *ngIf="editing"> <input [(ngModel)]="location.apName" type="text" placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/></td>

      <td *ngIf="!editing">{{location.locationName}}</td>
      <td id="locationNameInput" *ngIf="editing"> <input [(ngModel)]="location.locationName" type="text" placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/></td>

      <td *ngIf="!editing">{{location.lat}}</td>
      <td id="latInput" *ngIf="editing"> <input [(ngModel)]="location.lat" type="text" placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/></td>

      <td *ngIf="!editing">{{location.long}}</td>
      <td id="longInput" *ngIf="editing"> <input [(ngModel)]="location.long" type="text" placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/></td>

      <td *ngIf="!editing">{{location.mac}}</td>
      <td id="macInput" *ngIf="editing"> <input [(ngModel)]="location.mac" type="text" placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/></td>

      <td>
        <input type="button" *ngIf="!editing" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="engageEditing()" value="Edit" />
        <input type="button" *ngIf="editing" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateField(location)"  value="Update" />
        <input type="button" *ngIf="editing" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="cancelEditing()"  value="Cancel" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

This is my location.component.ts code

```
    engageEditing(){
    this.editing = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable `editing` for a single `location` instead of for the entire component, you need to *remember* it for each `location`. To add `editing` to your `location` object:

```
<tr *ngFor="let location of locations">
  <td *ngIf="!location.editing">{{location.apName}}</td>
  <td id="apNameInpit" *ngIf="location.editing"> <input [(ngModel)]="location.apName" type="text" placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/></td>

  ....

  <td>
    <input type="button" *ngIf="!location.editing" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="engageEditing(location)" value="Edit" />
    <input type="button" *ngIf="location.editing" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateField(location)"  value="Update" />
    <input type="button" *ngIf="location.editing" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="cancelEditing(location)"  value="Cancel" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

And update it in `engageEditing` and `cancelEditing`:

```
engageEditing(location) {
   location.editing = true;
}

cancelEditing(location) {
  location.editing = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than tracking `editing` as a boolean, track it as an integer. Then you know which index in your array is being edited.

```
this.editing = 5;
```

Then in your source you could use the for loop index to see if this is the current row being edited:

```
<tr *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index">
  <td *ngIf="editing == i">{{location.apName}}</td>
```

You'll also need to pass the index to your `engageEditing()` method so that it knows which row is being edited.

```
engageEditing(index) {
  this.editing = index;
}
```

And call it from your button and pass the index into it. Note the `i` we got from our `ngFor`.

```
<input type="button" *ngIf="!editing" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="engageEditing(i)" value="Edit" />
```

When nothing is being edited, set the value to `-1`. It might be tempting to use `0` but that's the index of the first item:

```
cancelEditing() {
  this.editing = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without index you can change your model of locations to:

```
locations = [{
  name: "apName",
  value: null,
  slackMemberID: "something"
  }
...
]

<tr *ngFor="let location of locations; let i = index" 
    (click)="markToEdit(location.name)">
   <td *ngIf="editing !== location.name">{{location.apName}}</td>
   <td id="location.name" *ngIf="editing === location.name">
     <input [(ngModel)]="location.value" type="text" 
            placeholder="{{location.slackMemberID}}"/>
   </td>
</tr>


public markToEdit(name: string){
  this.editing = name;
}
```

Or use Reactive forms and in the end you have values in

> form.value